# How to create \ssearrow with two heads

Tags: fonts, symbols, arrows

I'm using `\ssearrow` to denote a deformation retraction in algebraic topology. I want to use the same arrow, but with two heads for a strong deformation retraction. It doesn't exist in MnSymbol.

Is there a way to add another head to `\ssearrow`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}
\def\SSEarrow{\ensuremath{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-60}{$\twoheadrightarrow$}}}
\begin{document}

\Huge\SSEarrow
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: At 15yrs old, you friggin rock my friend. Thank you so much.